# Latexdiff support for Lyx

Tags: lyx, latexdiff, bash

As a regular LyX-user i'd love to know if there exists some back-end to latexdiff available for Lyx.

Currently i'm using the following bash commands to get what I want.

```
new=MyFileName
old=MyFileName_old

new_lyx=${new}.lyx
old_lyx=${old}.lyx

new_tex=${new}.tex
old_tex=${old}.tex

lyx --force-overwrite --export pdflatex $new_lyx
lyx --force-overwrite --export pdflatex $old_lyx

latexdiff $old_tex $new_tex > diff.tex

pdflatex diff.tex
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LyX has no implementation using `latexdiff`. The LyX way of comparing two documents is to do Tools > Compare, select the two files and choose "OK". If you had checked the checkbox, LyX will show the differences using its change tracking tools so that you can navigate between them.

Comment: +1 You could not only navigate between them, but also produce a PDF-diff as output (which is the main purpose of `latexdiff`).